# How to provide better UX for a list of user consents

Tags: usability, checkboxes, readability, gdpr, consent

I'm working on a UI that requires end user consent to proceed with a sign-up. Thought of using inline checkboxes within the consent statement. As you see below...

[image]

I have not come across this method and I doubt weather this improves readability and usability or making it worse. Is there any way I can simplify / improve this?

**Notes**:

- *Assume that the user persona is a typical user on a typical signup flow*
- *This UI is used in achieving [GDPR](https://www.eugdpr.org/) compliance in a user signup process*

---

**[Edit]** : 
Came up with two more methods to improve UX, But for a single Purpose, Some of our UX engineers still think the inline method is effective. Any thoughts ?

***Option 2***: Ideal for 2 purposes...
[image]

***Option 3***: Ideal for many purposes...
[image]

Comment: Have you not got a company privacy policy that outlines in detail how you use the customers' data that achieves GDPR compliance? I'd say you're making usability worse due to the excessive clicking and ease of the user missing one or two tick boxes.

Comment: @K.J The page containing this UI provides a default UX and the page is fully customizable by any third party reseller etc. We are trying to provide the best default template out of the box. So this can be customized to each organization's policies and to their own accord to achieve GDPR compliance. 

Agree with you on GDPR's impact on UX in a bad way. I guess It's a conscious decision that each organization has to make.

Answer (score 2):

We've carried out user research in a similar context, where they consent to sharing information. What stands out is that the average user doesn't want to read. If there is action required on part of the user, its better to make it distinct and clear. For your solution to work, the user would need to read the whole paragraph, which they usually don't like.

Why not make a simple list of check-boxes?

Comment: Great input, Thanks! 
Yes, We came up with two more designs, but its a split decision, so wanted to have more opinions.

Answer (score 1):

[check]Full name (educational purposes) 
[check]Address (educational purposes) 
[check]First name (Research purposes) 
[check]Birth date (Research purposes) 
[check]Birth date (Test purposes) 
[check] Email (Test purposes) 
[CHECK/UNCHECK ALL]

We would like to get your approval for use of your info as displayed above. Please review the fields and confirm what you agree with.

Altough I must admit having so much checks for privacy will make user pretty scared.

Comment: Would't repeating the purpose be making it worse? Was going for a natural reading pattern. Yes, too much checkboxes are bad UX but this is to comply with a certain data protection regulation policy. You will experience this in near future if you are in Europe etc..

Answer (score 0):

How about a table representation? The benefits:

- this is a classic widget, everyone is familiar with it
- scales well to large numbers of data types and purposes
- tables can be sorted by clicking on the column title, and users are familiar with this feature
- zebra stripes make it easier to discriminate rows
- tables can be skimmed easily

[image: Data types and purpose of collection]

Some comments about your prototypes:

- The first one provides no easy way to approve all uses, so a lot of clicking will be required.
- The GDPR doesn't demand a checkbox for every type of data. It is great if the system allows users to select exactly what they want to share; but if you did it only because you thought that's what the regulation wants - it is not the case.

I like the idea behind the first prototype and I am curious to find out what your usability tests have revealed and what you chose in the end. It would also benefit future archaeologists.